# Laravel ubuntu throws Fatal Error Exception

Tags: ubuntu, laravel

I'm trying to run a laravel project on Ubuntu but it doesn't work for some reason. I'm using **Apache 2**, **MySQL** and I have installed **composer**,**mcrypt** and **curl**.
I have downloaded my laravel project using **git**, then run composer install, created the database, **set permissions to 775** for app/storage directory and the project returns an unknown stack trace in a non existent view.Here is a [screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nky23.png) of the error.Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: Here is the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5YMJGekg) with the code of the cached page.
Thank you

P.S - The app runs with the same configuration on a windows 7 machine with wamp x64 installed.

Comment: This looks like a permissions issue, are you sure you included all of the subfolders in app/storage when you set the permissions?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer
I tried sudo chmod -R 775 app/storage from the root directory of laravel. No error occured


Edit: it's weird because this is happening in three installations 2 in VM php webservers and one in my local PC, all using ubuntu, and same components

Comment: do you have php5-curl, php5-mcrypt installed?

Comment: The issue looks like it's stemming from a view. Have you cleared cache and/or examined the view for errors?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have already install curl and mcrypt and also tried php artisan cache:clear command multiple times with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was not that difficult actually. After reading the **log files** carefully I found out that an **external library** I created was **not auto-loading**, I just added the directory of my external libraries in the **composer autoload** function and everything works as expected. 
I want to thank everyone for their suggestions, I hope this answer will help some people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `artisan cache:clear`. If that doesn't help, you'll need to look at what is present at line 74 of the cached view file that is referenced in the error (see upper left corner of the screenshot).

Comment: I've already tried artisan cache:clear with no success.
I tried to debug line 74 in the cached view file but everything seems OK.
Here is the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5YMJGekg) with the code of the cached page.
I think the code is not the issue because the applications runs with no problems on a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the view cache file permission has changed.

Try delete all cache files inside `*/app/storage/views/`, and let Laravel generate the cache again

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Tried that also, it keeps generating 2 cached views files with the same error.